# Practical feasibility of proving a plaintext hash relationship with a zk-SNARK

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I am interested in the practicality of using generic SNARK techniques to prove the following relation.

Let `E` and `E'` be two ElGamal ciphertexts. They have the form
`E = (E1, E2) = (g^r, M*PK^r)` and `E' = (E1', E2') = (g^r', M'*PK^r')`.

There is also a hash function `H`.

All of these are public: `E`, `E'`, `PK`, `H`.

I want to prove that `M' = H(M)`. I do not hold the secret key associated with the public key `PK`, but I do know the randoms `r` and `r'` that were used for the encryptions.

In particular, my witness is `(r,r')` and the SNARK verification circuit will:

1. Use `PK`, `r`, and `E2` to decrypt `M`.
2. Use `PK`, `r'`, and `E2'` to decrypt `M'`.
3. Output accept iff `M' = H(M)`.

**My questions are:**

- Can someone provide a rough intuition for how practical proving this statement will be? I am more sensitive to verification time and proof size than I am to prover time.
- Are there any hash functions that are particularly well-suited for this kind of task? (I have heard of the existence of Poseidon, but there seem to be a few SNARK friendly hash functions and I haven't yet gotten to the bottom of how they compare.)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving this statement is practical. I was able to do it using gnark (a zk-SNARK library). The backend uses the Groth16 proving system, which is very efficient; proof sizes depend on the underlying elliptic curve and other parameters, but should be on the order of a couple hundred bytes. Proof generation time is fast: on the order of one second. Verification time is two orders of magnitude faster.

I have done no optimisation, so these runtimes may be much worse than what someone else can do.

I used the Gnark implementation of MiMC, a zk-SNARK friendly hash function.

Comment: This sounds very interesting. If it is open source, could you please provide a link?